# Automate loading URL in Chrome using console dev tools

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-devtools

## Issue

Using Chrome dev tools, I need to:

- Be able to automate loading a series of urls in chrome dev;
- Use a dataset to provide the parameterized query string variables;
- Once each page loads then execute a jQuery script in Chrome console.

### Data

I have a JSON dataset that I would like to pass in to the URL as query string parameters  The data can be easily converted to any other format for any solution/ideas (e.g. csv, any relational db, etc.).  For example, if the following is the url pass in the query string parameter variable using my JSON/db dataset:

- http://www.example.net/products?itemnumber={itemnumber}

I am not sure what's possible in chrome dev but can't seem to find a way to power a loop using dev tools to automate looping through a series of web pages

If the following are all the url parameters, how can I pass in each value from the JSON/or from a file/or from any db to then load that url in Chrome for each {itemnumber} parameter?

```
[
{"itemnumber": "54"},
{"itemnumber": "82"},
{"itemnumber": "41"},
{"itemnumber": "76"}
]
```

### Scripting

In chrome dev console, as each page loads is it possible to execute a jQuery console script?  I'm able to run my script on each page one at a time manually, but I have hundreds of pages to load.

For example, say I wanted to run the following script as each page loaded.  Is it possible?

```
var arr = []; 
jQuery('#BasicInfo > table > tbody > tr >').each(function (i, v) 
{
    var obj = {}; 
    var $this = jQuery(this);  

    obj.orgid = jQuery('#org').val();
    obj.userid = jQuery('#userid').val();
    obj.companyname = jQuery('#companyname').val();
    arr.push(obj);  
});  
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). It's a project from the Chrome DevTools team. It's much better suited to handle your use case.